# OAuth2.0 User-Flow refresh_token is never returned

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, refresh-token

I have been searching for days and trying different methods with no luck to my problem. You are welcome to link me to something but I have probably already looked.

My issue / steps are:

- Trying to get an access_token with refresh_token from a JS browser
  POST
- Initial POST works fine but never returns a refresh_token
- Tried adding to the POST 'scope=full refresh_token' and many other combinations
- On salesforce.com the connected app has 'full api refresh_token offline_access'
- Token expires set to 1 hour

It never returns the refresh_token `:S` is it meant to? If not how do I get one for without using a web app?

Also when I include `scope=full refresh_token` on my post I get the following errors:

`error=invalid_scope&error_description=the%20requested%20scope%20is%20not%20avai
 lable`

When not using scope the implicit token works on api calls until it expires.

Comment: Just doing some more looking for any solution, found the same problem on salesforce forums three years unresolved:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AtMIAU

Comment: Have you found solution or response from Salesforce Support saying that documentation is wrong?

Comment: Another topic unresolved on discussion forums: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000g0CuIAI